# How Do I change every second elements class using PHP?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to change the CSS class of every second element within an included partial. Here is a code example of the output I want:

```
<p class="rec"></p>
<p class="sent"></p>
<p class="rec"></p>
<p class="sent"></p>
```

This is what I tried it so far:

```
<?php $derp = (isset($derp) && $derp == 'rec') ? 'sent' : 'rec'; ?>
<p class='<?php echo $derp; ?>'>
//CONTENT
</p>
```

I need help to get this working. I don't want to use the **nth-child** selector or JavaScript to change the class.

//update:

```
    @forelse($statuses as $status)
        @include('statuses.partials.status')
    @empty
    <div class="notif blue">
        <span>This user hasn't yet posted a status.</span>
        <span class="icon icon-info-sign"></span>
    </div>
    @endforelse
```

The partial get looped like this.

Comment: `$derp = ($derp == 'rec') ? 'sent' : 'rec'` should alternate

Comment: Undefined variable: derp (View: /home/vagrant/code/larabook/app/views/statuses/partials/status.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/code/larabook/app/views/statuses/partials/status.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/code/larabook/app/views/statuses/partials/status.blade.php)

Comment: Ha, that error is exactly what the isset($derp) is supposed to prevent, my apologies. Actually, I think its correct as written in your question. What output are you actually getting? What is the rest of the php code that writes out multiple <p> tags in a loop?

Comment: I only get the class rec back in all p's. I just updated my post with the code how the partial gets included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure CSS for this, using the `nth-child` selector and the `even` and `odd` parameter. In your CSS file simply add:

```
p:nth-child(odd) {
    // This is the odd element so 1, 3, 5, .. element
}
p:nth-child(even) {
    // This is the even element so 2, 4, 6, .. element
}
```

Comment: Did you read the part where I said I don't want to use this CSS selector?

Comment: @RobbyBubble, may I ask why you don't want to use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I had to keep the code outside of the included partial and not in the partial itself. This made the difference! Anyways, still appreciate the given help!